# Update multiple data in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Consider the following sample and suggest proper way to handle this problem or clear my mind from this kind of thought

```
data(){
   return{
       a: true,
       b: 5
   }
},
someMethod: function(){
    /*Currently update using the following lines,
      this.a = false
      this.b = 6
    */
    //Is there anything to update multiple attributes at a single line
    //Like in ReactJS
    //this.setState({})
    //Or correct my VueJS knowledge if im wrong 
}
```

Comment: `this.a = this.b = false`

Comment: I'm sorry. Consider a and b as different objects. Will update questions now!

Comment: vm.myData = {a: false, b: 6}, then make your data object have single data object inside it called myData.

Comment: this is awesome. But i need to use `myData.a` on all the reference instead of `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort of do what you're asking with [`Object.assign(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). It offers the shallow merge as in `this.setState`, and you can set base level properties this way

Vue also has [`vm.$set(this, propName, value)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) and [`Vue.set(this, propName, value)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set), although these offer similar functionality, they don't *merge* existing props with the new ones (they simply override), and they don't allow you set base level properties using the same syntax as `this.setState({})` but would require you to use `Vue.set(this, propName, {})`

```
// Poor mans setState(...), only using the shallow merge
methods: {
    setState(obj) {
        Object.assign(this, obj)
    },
}
```

[See attached pen](https://codepen.io/kristofferostlund/pen/RVoBxg?editors=1011)

Comment: If you need IE11 support Object.assign will not work since that browser lacks the feature. You can use the Lodash polyfill for _.assign.